# store a video from .ppt extension presentation in the PC

Tags: vba, powerpoint, embedded-video

I want to take a video and store it in a folder using VBA (the video was inserted using INSERT->Video->Video on my PC). In .pptx and .pptm extension presentation I can just add .zip extension to convert it to a zip file and the extract the content of it including the videos (The videos are stored it ppt/media folder).

In ppt files, if I put the .zip extension I cannot extract the content. Another thing that I tried was to save it as pptx file and the add the extension .zip. Like that I could extract the content but the videos where not there.

Answer (score 0):

> > In ppt files, if I put the .zip extension I cannot extract the content.

Right.  Because PPT files aren't ZIP files under the hood.  They're an entirely different format.

Prior to PPT 2010, the videos aren't part of the file; they're always linked.  If they play correctly, it means that they're out there as regular video files.  You just need to figure out where.  If they don't play, they might still be there but not playing for other reasons.

If you need help working out how to trace the link to find the file, ask.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. At least I know that it is impossible to make with .ppt extension.